# javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException error -codenameone

Tags: codenameone

Whenever I try to access the json data from the server using ConnectionRequest the following error is thrown. What might be the reason?

```
[Network Thread] 0:0:45,284 - Exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException - sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1917)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:301)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:295)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1471)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:212)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:936)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:871)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1043)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1343)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1371)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1355)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:563)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1511)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1439)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:338)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaSEPort.getResponseCode(JavaSEPort.java:8027)
    at com.codename1.io.ConnectionRequest.performOperation(ConnectionRequest.java:702)
    at com.codename1.io.NetworkManager$NetworkThread.run(NetworkManager.java:282)
    at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread.run(CodenameOneThread.java:176)
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:387)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:229)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:124)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1453)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:145)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:131)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:382)
    ... 23 more
```

I wonder if this issue affects the app. P.S I've tested it in the simulator.

Comment: This is an exception from the oracle JVM which can't verify the given URL's certificate. This can happen if the JVM is older or if the certificate has a problem along the way.

Comment: what sort of problem with the certificate could happen "along the way" ? im getting this now with one server im trying to connect to in cn1.